# Best way to multiply corresponding values in two maps

Tags: java, loops, hashmap, sum

How can you multiply the values of map1 to it's corresponding values in map2? I've tried two for loops, but it iterates through both maps 16 times. Assuming that both maps will always be the same length.

```
Map<String, Integer> map1= new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Integer> map2= new HashMap<>();

map1.put("one", 1);
map1.put("two", 2);
map1.put("three", 3);
map1.put("four", 4);

map2.put("one", 1);
map2.put("two", 2);
map2.put("three", 3);
map2.put("four", 4);

//map1 = {(one, 1), (two, 2)... etc
//map2 = the same

for(Integer num:map1.values()){
    for(Integer num2:map1.values()){
        total = num * num2;}}
System.out.println(total);
```

I'm doing something wrong. I would like to multiply each value and get that sum i.e. (1 * 1) + (2 * 2)...

Comment: do you know the keys which you need to multiple in advance?

Comment: @AntonBelev it would be each key in the map

Comment: for(Integer num:map1.values())[    <--don't use a bracket there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stream the entries, multiply each’s value by its matching value in the other map, then sum:

```
int sum = map1.entrySet().stream()
  .mapToInt(e -> e.getValue() * map2.get(e.getKey()))
  .sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

Key/value pairs in java maps are unordered. There is no guarantee that when you iterate over the values below that you will get the values in the same order.

```
for(Integer num:map1.values())[
    for(Integer num2:map1.values()){
        total = num * num2;}}
System.out.println(total);
```

The following would do it

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map1.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    int value = entry.getValue();
    total += value * map2.get(key);
}
System.out.println(total);
```

The above code is assuming that you always have the keys from `map1` in `map2` ! The complexity of this is O(n)* O(1), where n is the number of keys in `map1`. Accessing the values in `map2` is considered constant.

Comment: The code you suggests does the same thing. Results in an answer of 9 when I'm looking for an answer of 30.

Comment: Ah it's because you need to increment total. So it's `+=`

Answer (score 0):

You should be iterating the keys of one map, get related value from the other map (possibly using `getOrDefault` to return a default value for the missing ket) and calculate the total of their products:

```java
int total = 0;

for (String key : map1.keySet()) {
    total += map1.get(key) * map2.getOrDefault(key, 0);
}
```

---

Similar solution using Stream API:

```
int total = map1.entrySet().stream()
    .mapToInt(e -> e.getValue() * map2.getOrDefault(e.getKey(), 0))
    .sum();
```